# Is there a Restful Blog API

Tags: api, rest, blogs

I can't seem to find a true restful Blog API - are there any? 
I'm writing some blog software and wondered if there was a standard restful API, if not I'll go buy the RESTful Web Services book and design my own.

Comment: Here are some resources: - http://theamiableapi.com/api-design-resources/ - http://blog.apigee.com/taglist/restful - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/api-craft - http://mattgemmell.com/2012/05/24/api-design/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about [AtomPub](http://www.atomenabled.org/developers/protocol/#whatIsAtom)?

> Atom is the name of an XML-based Web
>   content and metadata syndication
>   format, and an application-level
>   protocol for publishing and editing
>   Web resources.

It isn't limited to blogs, but blogs certainly fall under the realm of applications are used for "publishing and editing Web resources".

Comment: AtomPub is being used in many places now, with Microsoft's Live services, Google's GData, and many blog systems. Learning it now would be a great idea.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for - i'd forgotten Atom had a publishing spec as well, +1 stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about REST, but have you look at MetaWeblog API? It's XML-RPC though.